# Is it possible in C to assign pointer to an array or change to address of array to the pointer address?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to assign pointer returning function to an array, is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * arrayReturn(int *q){ // example function
    return q;
}
int main()
{
    int z[3] = { 1 , 2 , 3};
    int q[3];
    q = *(int [3]) arrayReturn(z); 
    printf("%d %d %d", q[0],q[1], q[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

This below code is close to what I want, but this is not an array anymore.

```
int (*c)[3] = (int(*)[3])arrayReturn(z); 
printf("%d %d %d", c[0][0],c[0][1], c[0][2]);
```

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer

Comment: No. You can't change an address of an existing object.

Comment: Just declare `q` as `int *`.

Comment: What advantage are you looking for in making `q` an array? Are you trying to copy the data from `z` into a new space `q`? Or do you just want another way to point to the data in `z`?

Comment: You might think that you need an array to use `q[0]`, but you don't. Using square brackets is a kind of "syntactic sugar" for us, when we know that a pointer points to an array. `q[2]` is the same expression as `*(q + 2)`. An expression with the name of an array decays to a pointer to the first element of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot reassign an array as you do here:

```
int q[3];
q = *(int [3]) arrayReturn(z);
```

If you want to copy the *contents* of `z` to `q`, you can do that with the `memcpy` library function:

```
memcpy( q, z, sizeof z );
```

but the `=` operator isn't defined to copy array contents.

Otherwise, the best you can do is declare `q` as a pointer and have it point to the first element of `z`:

```
int *q = z; // equivalent to &z[0]
```

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `*` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array - that's why the above assignment works.

Arrays in C are simple sequences of elements - there's no metadata indicating their size or type, and there's no separate pointer to the first element.  As declared, the arrays are

```
   +---+
z: | 1 | z[0]
   +---+
   | 2 | z[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | z[2]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
q: | ? | q[0]
   +---+
   | ? | q[1]
   +---+
   | ? | q[2]
   +---+
```

There's no separate object `q` to assign *to*.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable which contains an address of memory.
Array is just a place in the memory that occupies so many bytes.
As a result, they are very different objects and cannot be assigned to each other.

However, a pointer can be used to point to an array and as a result can be used in copying data from one array to another, for example, using `memcpy`.

```
int c[3];
memcpy(c, arrayReturn(z), sizeof(c));
```

Of course, there is no checking of array sizes done and it is assumed that the size of an array to which points the return of the *arrayReturn()* is big enough to be copied to *c*. Neither there is a way to find out about the size of the array which it points to.